# Cassandra lost data after restarting

Tags: cassandra

I meet a problem. I generate some data, and get all of them. It works well. Afterwards, I shutdown all CassandraDaemons and restart them, I fail to get all data because data for some columns were lost. I don't know why this happens. Is there anyone could give me some advice? Thanks very much. By the way, I use Cassandra 2.1, and replication factor is 1.

Comment: With Cassandra you can query at different consistency levels (CL).What CL are you writing and reading at and how are you writing / reading (i.e. cqlsh or driver etc)?

Comment: The consistency level is ONE. I write and read data by thrift API.

Comment: It seems that Cassandra failed to replay the commitlog when restarting, which causes data loss. But I don't know why. One solution to fix data losss is to force flush data into SSTable using nodetool before killing CassandraDaemons.

Comment: Sorry, I think it's because that I clear cache before I killing Cassandra. thought the cached memory won't be released when the daemon was still running. However, I was wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I think it's because that I clear cache before I killing Cassandra. thought the cached memory won't be released when the daemon was still running. However, I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Cassandra failed to replay the commitlog when restarting, which causes data loss. But I don't know why. One solution to fix data losss is to force flush data into SSTable using nodetool before killing CassandraDaemons.

Comment: You could always drain before stopping the nodes. What kind of errors do you see on commitlog replay?

Comment: Actually, I don't see any ERRORs about replaying commitlog, but I see information like "No commitlog files found; skipping replay". So, when write a commitlog, isn't the data directly written into disk ? The cached commitlog are drained together ?  I am not sure about the implementations. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So the best resource here would be the docs on how Cassandra writes data: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html

Comment: If theres no commitlogs this isn't unusual, if you drain before stopping you should not have any data loss on that node on restart